# Use a Cell Value as a Worksheet Name

Tags: excel, vba

I want to paste data from a Workbook to another workbook into a sheet which has the name of a cell value. I don't know if that's possible, but I'm struggling with that and I can't find anything similar on internet.

This is my code so far:

```
'This creates a sheet from a range and gives it the name of the cell so it can be from 5 to 10 sheets'

For Each Cell In Range("G5:G15")
    If Cell.Value <> "" Then
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = Cell.Value
    End If
Next
```

After other code which is not important, I made this:

```
Dim AutoFilterRng As Range
Dim WorksheetName As String

For Each Cell In Range("H5", Range("H5").End(xlDown))
    If Cell.Value <> "" Then
        WorksheetName = Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value    
        Workbooks.Open MJFile                    'Opens the file where data I want to copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:U").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="*" & Cell.Value    'Filters depending on the cell value
        With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
            Set AutoFilterRng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        End With
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Count - 1).Copy
        Workbooks.Open WBOR    'Opens the Workbook where I want to paste data
        Worksheets(WorksheetName).Range("A1").Paste    'This gives an  error and it is where I would like to paste my data
        Workbooks.Open MJFile
        AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Next
```

Thank you very much in advance

If you want to see the whole code:

```
Sub AddTO()
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

'Open TO FIle'

Dim WBOR As String
Dim MJFile As String
Dim TOFile As String
Dim Path As String

WBOR = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name

'On Error GoTo Fin
MsgBox "Choose Bear File"
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Filters.Clear
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = -1 Then
        TOFile = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

Workbooks.Open TOFile

'Filter Bear File to Only Necessary TO'
Dim NameRng As Range
Dim TORng As Range
Dim DeliveryWeek As String
Dim i As Long

Workbooks.Open WBOR
Set NameRng = Worksheets("Tasks_Orders_Info").Range("E5", Range("E5").End(xlDown))
Workbooks.Open TOFile
Set TORng = Worksheets("WS Lead Plan1").Range("G2", Range("G2").End(xlDown))
Workbooks.Open WBOR
DeliveryWeek = "*Week_" & Worksheets("Tasks_Orders_Info").Range("C5").Value & "*"

Workbooks.Open TOFile
For i = TORng.Count To 1 Step -1
    Select Case True
        Case TORng.Cells(i) Like DeliveryWeek
        Case Else
            TORng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End Select
Next i

'Add TO to MJ File'
Workbooks.Open WBOR
TORng.Copy
Worksheets("Tasks_Orders_Info").Range("G5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Tasks_Orders_Info").Range("G5").End(xlDown).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Workbooks.Open TOFile
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Range("H5:H15") = "=IF(ISERR(FIND("" "",Table2[@Coder])),"""",LEFT(Table2[@Coder],FIND("" "",Table2[@Coder])-1))"
Range("I5:I15") = "=MID(Table2[@Coder],SEARCH("" "",Table2[@Coder],1)+1,SEARCH("" "", Table2[@Coder],SEARCH("" "",Table2[@Coder],1)+1)-SEARCH("" "",Table2[@Coder],1))"
Range("J5:J15") = "=IFERROR(MID(Table2[@Coder],FIND("" "",Table2[@Coder],FIND("" "",Table2[@Coder])+1)+1,FIND("" "",Table2[@Coder],FIND("" "",Table2[@Coder],FIND("" "",Table2[@Coder])+1)+1)-FIND("" "",Table2[@Coder],FIND("" "",Table2[@Coder])+1)-1),"""")"

Form1 = "=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(H5,G5,1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(I5,G5,1)),IF(J5="""",FALSE,ISNUMBER(FIND(J5,G5,1)))),LEFT(G5,FIND(""  "",G5,1)-3),IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(H5,G6,1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(I5,G6,1)),IF(J5="""",FALSE,ISNUMBER(FIND(J5,G6,1)))),LEFT(G6,FIND(""  "",G6,1)-3),IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(H5,G7,1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(I5,G7,1)),IF(J5="""",FALSE,ISNUMBER(FIND(J5,G7,1)))),LEFT(G7,FIND(""  "",G7,1)-3),IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(H5,G8,1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(I5,G8,1)),IF(J5="""",FALSE,ISNUMBER(FIND(J5,G8,1)))),LEFT(G8,FIND(""  "",G8,1)-3),IF(OR("
Form2 = "ISNUMBER(FIND(H5,G9,1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(I5,G9,1)),IF(J5="""",FALSE,ISNUMBER(FIND(J5,G9,1)))),LEFT(G9,FIND(""  "",G9,1)-3),IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(H5,G10,1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(I5,G10,1)),IF(J5="""",FALSE,ISNUMBER(FIND(J5,G10,1)))),LEFT(G10,FIND(""  "",G10,1)-3),IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(H5,G11,1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(I5,G11,1)),IF(J5="""",FALSE,ISNUMBER(FIND(J5,G11,1)))),LEFT(G11,FIND(""  "",G11,1)-3),IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(H5,G12,1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(I5,G12,1)),IF(J5="""",FALSE,ISNUMBER(FIND(J5,G12,1)))),LEFT(G12,FIND(""  "",G12,1)-3),IF("
Form3 = "OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(H5,G13,1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(I5,G13,1)),IF(J5="""",FALSE,ISNUMBER(FIND(J5,G13,1)))),LEFT(G13,FIND(""  "",G13,1)-3),IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(H5,G14,1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(I5,G14,1)),IF(J5="""",FALSE,ISNUMBER(FIND(J5,G14,1)))),LEFT(G14,FIND(""  "",G14,1)-3),IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(H5,G15,1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(I5,G15,1)),IF(J5="""",FALSE,ISNUMBER(FIND(J5,G15,1)))),LEFT(G15,FIND(""  "",G15,1)-3),""NOT FOUND"")))))))))))"
Range("B5", Range("B5").End(xlDown)) = Form1 + Form2 + Form3

Range("B5", Range("B5").End(xlDown)).Copy
Range("B5", Range("B5").End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("G5", Range("G5").End(xlDown)).ClearContents

'Create New Sheets"
Range("G5:G15") = "=IFERROR(CONCAT(RIGHT(Table2[@[TASK ORDER]],LEN(Table2[@[TASK ORDER]])-SEARCH("" TO"",Table2[@[TASK ORDER]],1)),""_"",H5),"""")"
Range("G5:G15").Copy
Range("G5:G15").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("H5", Range("H5").End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Delete

For Each Cell In Range("G5:G15")
    If Cell.Value <> "" Then
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = Cell.Value
    End If
Next

Worksheets("Tasks_Orders_Info").Activate

'Open MJ File'
MsgBox "Choose mj extraction"
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Filters.Clear
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = -1 Then
        MJFile = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

Workbooks.Open MJFile

'Delete non Users'
Dim mapjobdata As Range
Dim WorkUserRg As Range

Worksheets("map_jobs_-_feedback_and_observa").Range("A1").Select
Worksheets("map_jobs_-_feedback_and_observa").Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Worksheets("map_jobs_-_feedback_and_observa").Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

Set mapjobdata = Worksheets("map_jobs_-_feedback_and_observa").Range(Selection.Address)
Set WorkUserRg = mapjobdata.Find("Worked on by User", , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True).Offset(1, 0)
Set WorkUserRg = Worksheets("map_jobs_-_feedback_and_observa").Range(WorkUserRg, WorkUserRg.End(xlDown))

For i = WorkUserRg.Count To 1 Step -1
    If WorkUserRg.Cells(i) Like "*@email.com*" Then
        Else
            WorkUserRg.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

'Add MapJobs to each Sheet'
Workbooks.Open WBOR
Range("H5:H15") = "=IFERROR(RIGHT(Table2[@Coder],FIND("")"",Table2[@Coder],1)-(FIND("" ("",Table2[@Coder],1))),"""")"
Range("H5", Range("H5").End(xlDown)).Copy
Range("H5", Range("H5").End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Dim AutoFilterRng As Range
Dim WorksheetName As String

For Each Cell In Range("H5", Range("H5").End(xlDown))
    If Cell.Value <> "" Then
        WorksheetName = Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        Workbooks.Open MJFile
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:U").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="*" & Cell.Value
        With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
            Set AutoFilterRng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        End With
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Count - 1).Copy
        Workbooks.Open WBOR
        Worksheets(WorksheetName).Range("A1").Paste
        Workbooks.Open MJFile
        AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Next

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Fin:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This is the error I get and debug shows the next line:
[image: Run-time error]

Comment: Can you share your error stack. The following link on naming a worksheet by a cell value  might be helpful : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/name-a-worksheet-by-using-a-cell-value

Comment: Does the second workbook exist? Do you have to create it in code? The data to be posted "to another workbook" doesn't make part from your question? If yes, can you describe (in words) what does it mean? The sheet containing the second workbook sheet names, also provides the data to be copied? If not, what name that sheet does have?

Comment: @salsinga I successfully created the worksheets from a cell.value, what I want is to add data from Workbook 2 Sheet 1 to Workbook 1 Sheet cell.offset(0,-1).value or something like that.

Comment: Where did you declare and define `MJFile` and `WBOR`? When you wrote about first and second workbook, did you mean a set of such pairs? If  not, and you do not use an array of such full names, why opening them so many times?

Comment: What "I want is to add " means? Is it a range? If yes, how many columns and rows does it contain? Do you want to create the new sheet as described, on which workbook? On the one keeping the code, or on the other one?

Comment: @FaneDuru 1.- Yes, workbooks are already open since the beginning of the code which I omitted since is a very large code. 2.- No, I open it using the code, user should select the file. 3.- The file user open is called MJFile (as I set it in code), The current workbook was set to WBOR. I want to copy filtered data from MJFile Sheet 1 to WBOR Sheet Cell.value (which is a value from a range which the sheet was created from that name).

Comment: @FaneDuru I open it many times because sometimes it doesn't recognize the ranges, also, the name might vary. Worksheets names vary too. The only part which I have an error pop up is with the code ``Worksheets(WorksheetName).Range("A1").Paste ``

Comment: So, you define a specific workbook in the object `MJFile`, create a new sheet in the active workbook (`WBOR`) and copy the filtered data from `MJFile` into the newly created sheet. In a range starting with A1. Is that correct? The filter as you defined, returns what you expect?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, it filters correctly. Everything is fine until I want to use that code. Yes, it creates up to 10 sheets in ``WBOR``. And yes, that is what I want to do

Comment: You must try to avoid `Worksheets("xxx")`, `ActiveSheet`, `Range("H5",...)`. They are all the time refer to the Active sheet. That's why you 'need' to open the working workbook so many time (completely wrong). So, use `Dim sh as Workseet, MJFile as Workbook, MJFile as Workbook, sh1 as Worksheet` and then define those variable. Your `WBOR` must be defined outside the loop and then the newly created worksheet must be defined like 'Set sh = WBOR.Worksheets(WorksheetName)`. In this way you will have a reliable reference and everything will run smooth.

Comment: I cannot understand how the `MJFile` workbook was defined prior to coming in your posted code? Do you present a working code, or something to make you learn what is to be done? I wanted to make a piece of code, but in this circumstance I do not know what to use...

Comment: I see what you say makes sense. I uploaded the whole code.

Comment: @FaneDuru I set the worksheet name in the loop because it filters depending of the range for each cell, after filtering the data, it copies that data to the worksheet from the cell offset -1 row, and then it continues with the next cell which has a different value. Lets say, The range contains SH34, SH54, SH95. It creates 3 sheets with those names. So I filter the other workbook depending of the email of the user can be user1@email, user2@email etc. Ater filtering by user, it copies the data and pastes user@email filter to SH34, user2@email into SH54 and so on

Comment: I posted a piece of code which theoretically should work solving of your problem as I could understand it. The code is  not tested, because I cannot easily build similar workbooks. Try to understand it and implement in your project. Try using of `Option Explicit` and do the job in the way I tried to present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an untested code. I do not have the necessary data to test  it. It must give you some hints in order to understand what is to be done:

Please add `Option Explicit` on top of your module. This will oblige you to declare all variables...

```
Sub sheetsAddAndCopy()
Dim WBOR As Workbook, Wmjf As Workbook, shW As Worksheet, shMJ As Worksheet
Dim AutoFilterRng As Range, WorksheetName As String, cell As Range

Const MJFile As String = "your workbook full path"
Set WBOR = ThisWorkbook
Set Wmjf = Workbooks.Open(MJFile) 'Opens the file where data I want to copy

For Each cell In WBOR.Range("H5", Range("H5").End(xlDown))
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        WorksheetName = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        Set shW = WBOR.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count))
           shW.Name = WorksheetName
           Set shMJ = Wmjf.ActiveSheet
           shMJ.Range("A:U").AutoFilter field:=12, Criteria1:="*" & cell.Value    'Filters depending on the cell value
            Set AutoFilterRng = shMJ.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            shMJ.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(shMJ.AutoFilter.Range.count - 1).Copy shW.Range("A1")
          shMJ.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Yes, I think this helps. The error was just to use ``PasteSpecial`` instead of ``Paste``. Thanks for everything

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer BUT may help you:

```
Sub test()

    Dim shtName As String

    With ThisWorkbook

        'Let assume that the sheet name we want appears in Sheet3, range A1
        'Get sheet name
        shtName = .Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value
        'Activate sheet with name shtName
        .Worksheets(shtName).Activate

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I should not use `.paste` instead it should be `.PasteSpecial` and set the Worksheet. In this case `WorksheetName = Cell.Offset(0,-1).Value` and then set the Worksheet with that name so it will be `Dim CurrentWSName, Set CurrentWSName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(WorksheetName)` Code will be like this:

```
Dim AutoFilterRng As Range
Dim WorksheetName As String
Dim CurrentWSName As Worksheet

For Each Cell In Range("H5", Range("H5").End(xlDown))
    If Cell.Value <> "" Then
        WorksheetName = Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        Set CurrentWSName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(WorksheetName)
        Workbooks.Open MJFile
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:U").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="*" & Cell.Value
        With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
            Set AutoFilterRng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        End With
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Count - 1).Copy
        Workbooks.Open WBOR
        CurrentWSName.Activate
        Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        Workbooks.Open MJFile
        AutoFilterMode = False
        Workbooks.Open WBOR
    End If
Next
```